# How can I apply css transitions to a background image change?

Tags: javascript, css

If I'm using the below simple JS to change a background image on a timer, can I apply CSS transitions to make these fade in instead of just swapping instantly?

```
var images = new Array(
     '../images/pic1.jpg'
    ,'../images/pic2.jpg'
    ,'../images/pic3.jpg'
);
var i = 0;

function swap() {
    var elm = document.querySelector('.myCSSClass');
    if (i >= images.length) { i = 0 };
    elm.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[i] + ')';
    i += 1;
}

window.onload = setInterval(swap, 2000);
```

For instance, I'm trying in CSS:

```
.myCSSClass{
      transition: background-image linear 0.3s;
}
```

But not getting any result. I feel like this isn't possible because javascript is just overwriting the image?

Comment: Manually fade out the image within the javascript and not the CSS, correct?

Comment: Something like that would work, yes. `background-image` is not an [animatable CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

Comment: Ah I see, awesome, thank you.

Comment: You can't that kind transition, because you need _two_ images to interpolate in between, and background images are hard to manipulate, with opacity, because you will affect the entire element and all children to that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to make sure all the images are initially loaded to have the transition or each time you will call a new image you will get an abrupt change because it will be loading Or you have to wait for one cycle because your script will load the images within that cycle.

```js
var images = new Array(
  'https://picsum.photos/id/0/300/300', 
  'https://picsum.photos/id/10/300/300', 
  'https://picsum.photos/id/15/300/300'
);
var i = 0;

function swap() {
  var elm = document.querySelector('.box');
  if (i >= images.length) {
    i = 0
  };
  elm.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[i] + ')';
  i += 1;
}

window.onload = setInterval(swap, 2000);
```

```css
.box {
  transition: background-image linear 0.5s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  
  /* This will force the initial load of all the images*/
  background-image:
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/0/300/300),
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/300/300),
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/15/300/300);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

In the above you will have fading only on some browser like chrome. Here is another idea where I will consider another layer and rely on opacity change:

```js
var images = new Array(
  'https://picsum.photos/id/0/300/300', 
  'https://picsum.photos/id/10/300/300', 
  'https://picsum.photos/id/15/300/300'
);
var i = 0;

function swap() {
  var elm = document.querySelector('.box');
  if (i >= images.length) {
    i = 0
  };
  elm.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[i] + ')';
  i += 1;
}

window.onload = setInterval(swap, 2000);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 0 0;
  
  /* This will force the initial load of all the images*/
  background-image:
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/0/300/300),
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/300/300),
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/15/300/300);
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image:inherit;
  background-size:cover;
  animation:op 1s alternate linear infinite 1s;
}

@keyframes op {
   to {
     opacity:0;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: This stops the momentary flashing that was occuring, but the `transition: background-image linear 0.5s;` doesn't work for actually fading a picture in/out

Comment: @jamheadart on Chrome you have a fade animation but not on Firefox. The animation type of images is discrete but some browser do an effort to add interpolation (not all of them)

Comment: Ah I see, so I'd need to cater for all browsers (I am using Firefox atm)

Comment: @jamheadart will update with anothe trick, give me few minutes

Comment: I may have missed the change? :D

Comment: @jamheadart check the update ;) I got busy last night

Comment: Nice. I've accepted this as the answer for being so comprehensive, and providing an answer that is only using CSS on top of the javascript I already had. Perfect!